# How to create a shortcut?

Tags: vb.net, shortcut, late-binding

I need to create shortcuts for  selected files within  selected folders. On several sites (including stackoverflow) I found the following code:

```
Private Sub MakeShortcut(ByVal File As String, ByVal ShortcutFolder As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal WorkDirectory As String)
        Dim WshShell As Object = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim NewShortcut As Object = WshShell.CreateShortcut(ShortcutFolder & "\" & Name & ".lnk")

        NewShortcut.TargetPath = File
        NewShortcut.WindowStyle = 1
        NewShortcut.IconLocation = File & ",0"
        NewShortcut.WorkingDirectory = WorkDirectory
        NewShortcut.Save()
End Function
```

Of course I added a reference to `Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll` to my Project and "Imports IWshRuntimeLibrary" within the 'general' section of the form.

Nevertheless I do get the message "Option Strict dissallows late binding" for all appearances of "whshell." and "Newshortcut."

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: And you didn't think to Google for [Option Strict dissallows late binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efwbatax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: turn off option strict?

Comment: You should explore the types located in the namespace `IWshRuntimeLibrary`. Look for types named `WshShell` and `WshShortcut`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic Leave event giving errors when enabling option strict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541689/visual-basic-leave-event-giving-errors-when-enabling-option-strict)