# Visual Basic Leave event giving errors when enabling option strict

Tags: .net

I have this windows form with 8 textboxes which need to be validated. I wrote this leave procedure which seems to work fine. Then I turned on option strict, and now its giving errors that I guess I don't understand.

The full procedure is here:

```
Private Sub IsValidMeasurement(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtRoomTwoWidth.Leave, TxtRoomTwoLength.Leave, TxtRoomThreeWidth.Leave, TxtRoomThreeLength.Leave, TxtRoomOneWidth.Leave, TxtRoomOneLength.Leave, TxtHallwayWidth.Leave, TxtHallwayLength.Leave
    Dim valid As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(sender.Text, Sentinel)
    If valid Then
        'Do Nothing, Input was valid.
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number of inches.")
        sender.Text = ""
        sender.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

The errors are when I attempt to use the traits of the textbox: sender.Text, sender.focus(). The specific error says option strict disallows late binding. Can I get some help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (sender As **Object**, e As EventArgs)

uses late binding - please see reference [late and early bindnig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx)
So in simple words:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions,
>   disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in
>   an **Object** type

So in this particular case "use strict" will not work with **object**
Maybe you can define this as TextBox?

reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)

Comment: Well, I tried the line (sender As Textbox), that generated a ridiculous amount of errors. However, I did come up with a solution, which I will show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I used was that, the first statement inside the procedure I added

```
Dim textbox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox) ' explicitly cast sender from object to Textbox.
```

Then, rather than attempting to use sender.Text or sender.Focus(), I accessed them via textbox.Text and textbox.Focus()

No more errors.